# HTML/JavaScript Tooltips on buttons in a Colorbox lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, colorbox

What is the easiest way to attach HTML/JavaScript tooltips to the `cboxPrevious` and `cboxNext` buttons in a [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) lightbox?

To show what I have tried so far, here a simplified colorbox demo, taken from the Colorbox home page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Colorbox Example</title>
        <base href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
         $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', current: 'hallo'.link("http://google.com") });             
     });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Colorbox Demonstration</h1>
    <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
    <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee2.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
    <p><a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee3.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you open this page in a browser and click on the first link you get a Colorbox with arrows for previous and next image. **To these buttons I want to attach tooltips.**

I know how to attach a tooltip in HTML. Just add a title attribute:

```
<span title="Tooltip text">Some text</span>
```

So I tried it similarly in JavaScript, first for the `cbxCurrent` text: I modified the line

```
$(".group1").colorbox(...
```

so that it reads:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', current: '<span title="Tooltip text">Some text</span>' });
```

This works! But when I try it for the `previous` button it doesn't do anything:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', previous: '<span title="Tooltip text">Some text</span>' });
```

I think I have to attach the title attribute to the `cboxPrevious` background image (because the [used CSS file](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css) reveals that the background image contains the arrow while the text is indented into invisibility), but I don't know how to attach the tooltip to this element in the Javascript function.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('MY_ID').colorBox({
    onOpen: function() {
        $("#tt").tooltip("disable");
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        $("#tt").tooltip("enable");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me like this, sorry. Are the strings `#tt` correct? Even when I change it to `#cboxPrevious` the Colorbox lightbox won't show the content

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining your answer a little bit, please?

Comment: you have to custom change on jquery.colorbox.js. and use bootstrap tooltip